# port forwarding to docker instance for rdp

Tags: remote-desktop, docker, port-forwarding, azure

I have installed docker on my machine. On the ubuntu container I am using, I've installed all the stuff necessary to remote desktop via RDP. (like xrdp, tightvncserver, etc). Even remote-desktop from my host machine to the docker instance works fine.

Now assume I am trying to remote-desktop the host machine from another remote machine. Is there anyway I can configure my host machine such that it forwards any incoming rdp connection to my docker instance rdp port?

In other words, how can I rdp from a remote host to my target host's docker container running instance?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, I'm not familiar with Docker and its configuration, but this should get the data to where you want it.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.0.5:3389
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.10.0.5 --dport 3389 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.2
```

Comment: How to specify `--to-port` argument?

Comment: Actually, try using '--to-destination 192.168.0.0:3389' being your docker container.

Comment: I updated my answer to include SNAT for return traffic.  It makes the assumption your docker container is 10.10.0.5 and your host/iptables is 192.18.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to start your container using `-p`

```
docker run -p 3389 yourimage
```

from `docker run --help`:

```
-p, --publish list         Publish a container's port(s) to the host (default [])
```

If you installed the software to the running container (instead of using a Dockerfile), then you actually used docker the wrong way. Then you first have to create an image out of the running container and then start that image:

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] yourcontainer yourimage
docker run -p 3389 [OPTIONS] yourimage [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```